# Tag like content <> in chat messages not escaped properly in inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, global-inbox

[Original message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25975072#25975072) in chat (the message is never edited)

> @nhahtdh It gets even funnier with something like `((?<a>a)*(?<2>b)*(c)*){2}`

shows up in my inbox as:

[image: Martin Büttner: @nhahtdh It gets even funnier with something like ((?a)*(?b)*(c)*){2}]

As you can see, `<a>` and `<2>` are missing from the inbox. I expect them to show up normally as text.

Comment: When Chat sends an item to the inbox, it calls `Decode(RemoveTags(RenderMarkdownMini(...))).Trim()`. It's the `RemoveTags` call that removes your `<a>` and `<2>`. I don't know Chat well enough to tell you if it's [status-bydesign] (I will inquire shortly), but certainly it works exactly as the code is written.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: If you look at the message history, the `<a>` and `<2>` are between backticks. They should be treated as code instead of being removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed as of chat build 309 (already deployed as of current writing).

Comment: Would you mind leaving a message in Regex room for testing?

Comment: You should test it yourself in the [Sandbox](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1), by sending yourself replies with the message contents. You can see in that chatroom that I've already done the testing at my end.